# Why the size of my upload file of Cloud Storage Cloud is it "0 bytes" (Node)

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-storage, adonis.js

i try upload a pdf to Google cloud Storage but i dont know why the file size is 0 bytes...

already i have try resolve this during 3 days but i not have response..
this is my code:

```js
const  cv = request.file('cv')
  
      console.log(cv)
    
        const gc = await new Storage({
          projectId: GOOGLE_CLOUD_PROJECT_ID,
          keyFilename: GOOGLE_CLOUD_KEYFILE,
        })

        const bucked = gc.bucket('rootbusco')
        const file = bucked.file(cv.stream.filename)

         const stream = await cv.stream.pipe(file.createWriteStream({
          resumable: false,
          gzip: true,
          metadata: {
            contentType: cv.stream.headers['content-type']
          }
        }))

        stream.end(cv.stream.data);
```

thanks for the asks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are creating the `stream` from the your request file object(`cv.stream.pipe`), that is incorrect, you will only use that in the `stream.end()` to actually fill in the data, so if change this piece of your code to the following (untested) code, it should work:

```
const stream = file.createWriteStream({
    resumable: false,
    gzip: true,
    metadata: {
        contentType: cv.stream.headers['content-type']
    }
})
```